# PHP encourage loop part way through the loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am wanting to get a loop to loop without going through all the code for the loop. For instance in the example code I want to continue the loop without have to go through any of the if statements below the one that matches.

*NOTE: I know something similar to this example would be better done using a switch statement but my set of if statements are not as simple as this.*

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    if(is_varchar($value)){loop;}
    if(is_text($value)){loop;}
    if(is_mediumText($value)){loop;}
    if(is_boolean($value)){loop;}
    if(is_integer($value)){loop;}
    if(is_float($value)){loop;}
    if(is_double($value)){loop;}
}
```

Comment: Showing us the actual statements would be better.

Comment: add a break statement in the condition that matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont see a reason NOT to use `switch` here.

```
foreach ($x as $y) {
  switch ($y) {
    case 0: continue; break;
    case 1: continue; break;
    case 2: continue; break;
    case 3: continue; break;
  }
}
```

You can completely omit `continue;`, if the `switch`-statement is the only one within the `foreach`-loop

```
foreach ($x as $y) {
  switch ($y) {
    case 0: doSomethingA(); break;
    case 1: doSomethingB(); break;
    case 2: doSomethingC(); break;
    case 3: doSomethingD(); break;
  }
}
```

Update (after the update of the question):

The `switch`-statement is still useable (and in my opinion more readable)

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
  switch (true) {
    case is_varchar($value): continue; break;
    case is_text($value): continue; break;
    // And so on
  }
}
```

As long as the code simply does nothing you can also simplify it a little bit.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
  switch (true) {
    case is_varchar($value): 
    case is_text($value):
      continue;
    break;
    // And so on
  }
}
```

Comment: If you see the note I said that a switch statement does not work if the set of if statements I am using. I have changed the example code to reflect this.

Comment: @Brook: Didnt understand it the first time, but anyway: Dont see a problem :)

Comment: I didn't know you could use functions in a switch stament like that. I like it!

Answer (score 3):

Use [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

> continue is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($x as $y){
    if($y==0){continue;}
    if($y==1){continue;}
    if($y==2){continue;}
    if($y==3){continue;} }
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
foreach($x as $y) {

    if ($y == 1) {
        doThis();
        continue;
    }

    // or something like this?
    switch($y) {
          case 2:
              doThat();
              continue;
     }
}
```

Comment: I can't use a switch statement so it would be more like the your first example.